NPM SEMANTIC RELEASE | MAINTENANCE BRANCH
I am using the semantic release library to publish my react project.
The current version is v1.22.3. and I want to make a fix over the v1.21.1
I tried creating a branch name 1.21.8 and pushed and was getting the below error
Completed step "fail" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"
19:22:04 [1:52:04 PM] [semantic-release] › ✘  EINVALIDNEXTVERSION The release 1.21.2 on branch 1.21.8 cannot be published as it is out of range.
19:22:04 Based on the releases published on other branches, only versions within the range >=1.21.1 <1.21.2 can be published from branch 1.21.8.
How can I do this using maintenance branch? Tried going through the documentation and it's kind of confusing
They have mentioned like either pushing or merging to the maintenance branch, not sure which one to pick. Can someone help on this?
https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/usage/workflow-configuration#pushing-to-a-maintenance-branch
I am using the below config
branches: [
    { name: 'poc', channel: 'latest' },
    { name: 'stage', channel: 'latest' },
    { name: 'main', channel: 'latest' },
    { name: '1.21.8', range: "1.21.x", channel: "1.21.x" },
  ]

